# Realm.write is being skipped

Tags: ios, realm

I am using Realm and trying to reorder cells in my TableView. Behaviour that I find odd is that it works sometimes exactly like I want (it updates the data in Realm properly) but sometimes when it hits the line:

```
myRealm.write {
```

it does not go inside this block. Using breakpoints I can see it skips the whole block and goes directly to the end of this block. Because of this, even-though it gives the visual appearance that the tableView has been re-ordered, it has not been re-ordered in Realm.

I should note that I am using a column in a table in Realm called order as a means of storing order. Also, labels is the array from Realm of the Table that I am trying to order

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        //update when you move a row up
        if sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row {
            let lowerbound = destinationIndexPath.row
            let upperbound = sourceIndexPath.row
            do{
                let myRealm = try Realm()

                myRealm.write {

                    let labelAtSource = self.labels![upperbound]
                    labelAtSource.order = lowerbound

                    for i in lowerbound...upperbound-1{
                        let label = self.labels![i]
                        label.order = i+1
                    }
                }   
            }catch { }
        }else{ //when you move a row down
            let lowerbound = sourceIndexPath.row
            let upperbound = destinationIndexPath.row
            do{
                let myRealm = try Realm()

                myRealm.write {

                    let labelAtSource = self.labels![lowerbound]
                    labelAtSource.order = upperbound

                    for i in lowerbound+1...upperbound{
                        let label = self.labels![i]
                        label.order = i-1
                    }
                }
            }catch { }
        }
}
```

Comment: You're using a try right before your write call. Maybe it fails and so it doesn't execute the write anymore. Write a log in the catch block to see if it enters there.

Comment: It's going past the try and failing to run the myRealm.write block, i made a gif to show you what happens when i put a breakpoint on the try. https://i.imgur.com/pqT6a4B.gif

Comment: I don't know why that would be, but I believe your realm can't be initialized, and so calling a write block on a nil object, simply ignores it. Can you check whether you get a valid realm object before you attempt to write to it?

Comment: I'm having this same problem and haven't found a solution. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @DonFitz i believe I just upgraded to the newer version of Realm and it solved. This is what i ended up using: https://gist.github.com/dmathewwws/2d89dd2d5dad256989c92866659c9b13

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using Realm.beginWrite() and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a throwing initializer `Realm()` in a do-catch block without any error handling at all. I'd guess that this fails.
Instead of catching the error and let it disappear unhandled, I'd rather recommend to use `try!`, which would cause a runtime error here.

But then you should also ensure that you have accessed your Realm before at least once initially to avoid having to worry about failing schema migrations / validations at this point. Most errors which can still occur later with the default realm setup are typically only seen during development, e.g. when the Browser is attached to the simulator files.

Comment: It's going past the try and failing to run the myRealm.write block, i made a gif to show you what happens when i put a breakpoint on the try. https://i.imgur.com/pqT6a4B.gif

Comment: Could you share a reproducible case? We would like to investigate that further.

Comment: Also noticed same problem, started randomly and since them happens always. Same code was working before. Write block is not executed. I have it in a do ... try Realm()... catch _. The catch block not executed (have a breakpoint and print msg there). I'm executing this in the background         `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {...}`

Comment: Also: Using the simulator. After restarting the simulator (without reset) it's working again. I also had the Realm Browser open during the problem. Closed it before restarting the simulator. After closing Realm Browser, before restarting the simulator I did another test but the write block still not executed in only started working after the restart.

Comment: Another thing Realm browser *always* crashes when I update the database, curiously this time it didn’t. Maybe there’s a connection? v 0.93.2(7), Realm v. 0.94.1